# Build the rewrite rule with specific path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

At first, I sorry to make the simple question but I really didn't know how to build the rule with my special path.

My project path is like:

```
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/index.html
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/001.html
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/002.html
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/003.html
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/004.html
...and more
```

*With 123456 is the category number, it will be changed automatically but the file structure inside will be same.*

Now I have the mobile version:

```
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/**m_index.html**
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/m_001.html
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/m_002.html
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/m_003.html
www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/m_004.html
...and more
```

So my question is **How can I redirect to m_*.html when access by mobile?**

Ex:

index.html -> m_index.html 
001.html -> m_001.html
...

Any suggest?

Comment: Redirection is a possible approach to this, but usually not a good one. Instead use some routing script which delivers the desired markup code in background. Cleaner URLs, more flexibility, more fine grained control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MOBILE:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:MOBILE} =1
RewriteRule ^(cafe/[\w-]+/guide)/?$ /$1/m_index.html [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:MOBILE} =1
RewriteRule ^(cafe/[\w-]+/guide)/(?!m_)([\w-]+\.html)$ /$1/m_$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: It works. Your are awesome ! But I have some mistakes. My index.html is just show www.example.com/cate/123456/guide/ only NOT have index.html. Can you help me to adjust it a little bit.

Comment: No, I try access in mobile with .../guide/, it didn't redirect to /guide/sp_index.html but I try to type /guide/index.html it does...

Comment: The m_ and sp_ is same, I wrong when copy it......I did it. I add more rule like RewriteRule ^(category/[\w-]+/guide)/(?!sp_)$ /$1/sp_index.html [L,NC,R=301].  But in the PC, it also redirect to mobile site.

Comment: The new one is ok for mobile but in PC didn't. In PC it still redirects to mobile.

Comment: Due to `RewriteCond %{ENV:MOBILE} =1` it won;t redirect for PC. You probably have old browser cache.

Comment: You are right, the problem was about the cache. I clear all and it worked. Thank you for your help my life ^_^. Outside that, can you show me the document or resource to research about this. I want to research your code to understand.

Comment: There are various resources. Check http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php and http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708